# how do I use TimeSeriesSplit in xgb.cv

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, xgboost

I have trying to run XGBoost for time series analysis. these are my codes which are used else where

```
xgb1 = xgb.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,n_estimators=n_estimators,max_depth=max_depth,min_child_weight=min_child_weight,gamma=0,subsample=0.8,colsample_bytree=0.8,
                                reg_alpha=reg_alpha,objective='reg:squarederror', nthread=4, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27)
xgb_param = xgb1.get_xgb_params()
dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train)
cv_folds = 5
early_stopping_rounds = 50
cvresults = xgb.cv(dtrain=dmatrix, params = xgb_param,num_boost_round=xgb1.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=cv_folds,
                           metrics='rmse', early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
```

Obvious issue here is that I want to cross validate timeseries data and hence can't use the cv_folds = 5.

(How) can I use the `TimeseriesSplit` function within xgb.cv?

thanks,